# Silverlight: Fix for HyperlinkButton hover bug?

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, position

On hover of a HyperlinkButton in a vertical StackPanel, controls below the HyperlinkButton inch down a few pixels. It's kind of a weird bug, and I'm sure there's a fix, but the only HyperlinkButton bug fix I find relates to large text rendering a tad blurry on hover, not this positioning bug. Has anyone come across this?

XAML:

```
  <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   ...
    <StackPanel x:Name="Article1" Style="{StaticResource ArticleContainer}"
                Canvas.Top="46">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Article1Image" Style="{StaticResource ImageCategory}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Article1Title" Style="{StaticResource TitleText}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Article1Posted" Style="{StaticResource PostedText}"/>

        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Author1Link" Style="{StaticResource HLBStyling}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Article1By" Style="{StaticResource AuthorText}"/>
        </HyperlinkButton>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Article1Content" Style="{StaticResource ContentText}"/>

        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Article1Link" Style="{StaticResource HLBStyling}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Article1ReadMore" Style="{StaticResource ReadMoreText}"/>
        </HyperlinkButton>

    </StackPanel>
   ...
   </Canvas>
```

App.xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="ContentPanel" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="427"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="33"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ArticleContainer" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="195"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="230"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ImageCategory" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TitleText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="170"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PostedText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="230"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="AuthorText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="230"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ContentText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="90"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="230"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ReadMoreText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="HLBStyling" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: not this bug: http://peterbrady.net/News/Details/quick-fix-for-silverlight-hyperlinkbutton-rendering

Comment: What does your xaml look like? I am unable to reproduce the issue with 
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Hello World"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

Comment: I added the xaml. The only real difference I see between your code and mine is the Grid vs. Canvas.

Comment: Changed to use a Canvas and still unable to reproduce. I'm doing this all directly within MainPage

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the styling? added relevant app.xaml code. Also, I have two of these StackPanels in my canvas, both of them do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your the two styles you are using for HyperLinkButton (HLBStyling) and the TextBlocks they contain (AuthorText, ReadMoreText). 
If you remove the TextBlock and just set the Content of the HyperLinkButton, the problem goes away. Also if you remove the style from the TextBlocks within the buttons, the problem goes away.

Comment: Do you know what specifically is causing it though? Other than "your styles." That's more of a work around than a fix.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, I'm just looking for a deeper answer than that.

Comment: It's caused by the Height property of the TextBlock Style. you are setting the Height to 14, but the HyperLinkButton needs more space than that to do it's thing when you mouse over